# moment js not properly translating the date format for japanese locale

Tags: angularjs, character-encoding, momentjs

I need to translate the date format to Japanese locale but its showing output wrongly.I also tried by changing the locale of the browser but its not working in both chrome and IE

```
  app.filter('japan', function() {
          return function(dateString, format) {
              return moment().locale('ja').format('LLLL'); 
          };
         })
```

Output for the format is 2016蟷ｴ6譛�20譌･蜊亥燕11譎Ｎ蛻� 譛域屆譌･

Required output is  2016年6月20日午前11時30分 月曜日

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with Moment. This is [mojibake](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake). First, make sure that your site is using UTF8 or UTF16 encoding (UTF8 is the defacto standard). You may also need to adjust the `lang` attribute on your `<html>` element depending on the locale.

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe after adding UTF8 its working properly thanks lot for the help

Comment: Glad to hear that. I've added a more fleshed-out answer below. I would appreciate it if you mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Moment. It's an encoding problem known as [mojibake](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) and can happen when your page has an encoding that doesn't correctly handle the characters you are using. In general, it's preferable to use a neutral encoding like UTF-8 or UTF-16 (UTF-8 is the de-facto standard), and from the comments above, it sounds like this did indeed fix your issue.

Additionally, it is a good idea to set a `lang=""` attribute on the element containing your localized content (you can do this as high up as the `<html>` element), because certain characters can have different appearances depending on the locale.

To take your text as an example, the top-right portion of the character 曜 looks like 羽 with `lang="zh"`, but looks like two side-by-side ヨs with `lang="jp"`.

Comment: In chrome while loads page its displays correctly but it shows mojibake when we traverse back to the page from other page it again shows mojibake

Comment: Can you think of any reason why the encoding might not be getting set correctly when you traverse back to the page? I'm afraid I can't offer much advice without knowing more of the specifics of your situation.